# Component's property is not updated when using vuex-module-decorators

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-module-decorators

I am using VueJs 2.6 with TypeScript support and vuex-module-decorators to manage application state.

Here is one of my components:

```
const MyModule = namespace(`MyModule`);

... component definition ...

@MyModule.State('prop1')
public prop1!: SomeModel;
```

that is wired to a state module:

```
@Module({ namespaced: true })
export class MyModule extends VuexModule {
  public prop1!: SomeModel | null;
...
}
```

When a mutation in MyModule sets property prop1, the corresponding property in the component does not get updated. I checked, mutation is called correctly and state's property is updated.

How to make my component's properties update automatically after state gets changed?

Comment: did you find a solution? because i am searching to. with typescript it doesnt work but with plain js it does on my other application. can you provide help please if you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

i found it it was the Examination the suffix you added to be not null "!" if you remove it it will be updated. i do not why exactly it is working like this.